# How to write TeamCity build counter into FILE_VERSION_INFO of dll

Tags: git, dll, label, teamcity, fileversioninfo

We have a project in git repository which is built by TeamCity into mylib.dll

There is a build counter in TeamCity and we would like to label the commit being build with this counter and also to set this counter/label as FILE_VERSION_INFO in mylib.dll (right click -> Properties -> Details).

Is there any feature in TeamCity do it? We checked the meta-runner-power-pack, but we didn't find any tool how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To label sources of a particular build you can use [VCS Labeling build feature](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/VCS+Labeling).
There is [AssemblyInfo Patcher feature](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/AssemblyInfo+Patcher) in TeamCity which allows to add Assembly version.

Comment: It looks nice. And it is something similar available Unix GCC project as well?

Comment: This does not work in .NET Core. I found another approach for it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42293338/setting-net-core-library-assembly-file-nuget-package-version-at-build-time